# Regular expression to replace square brackets with angle brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like:

```
[a b="c" d="e"]Some multi line text[/a]
```

Now the part `d="e"` is optional. I want to convert such type of string into:

```
<a b="c" d="e">Some multi line text</a>
```

The values of `a` `b` and `d` are constant, so I don't need to catch them. I just need the values of `c`, `e` and the `text between the tags` and create an equivalent xml based expression. So how to do that, because there is some optional part also.

Comment: I assume there might be cases like: `[a b="<c>" d="e"]Some <element>here</element> too[/a]` ?

Comment: Anything can be in between the [a..]..[/a]

Comment: If "anything can be in between [a..]..[/a]" then you will generate an infinitely large regex which will be infinitely broken

Comment: I don't think, as there won't be any [/a] in the text, even if its present I need to match up to the first ending [/a]

Comment: You have said "the text can be anything" and "and there can't be HTML markup or scripts per se". So you have an undefined/contradictory problem and it's impossible to write a regex. Only you know what the grammar - if there is one - is for your multiline context. Only you can write a parser. And regexes will almost certainly lead to problems

Comment: Do you notice that your problem is horribly underspecified? Even with the amendments in the comments, there are a lot of dangerous assumptions and undefined special cases hanging around, ready to cause trouble. And while I *think* (after the current problem description) that this could be solved by a regular expression, it might *still* not be a good idea, what with changing requirements and updating the code to reflect them.

Comment: Assume your "anything" contains

`bookseller="Barnes&Noble"`

Then all the regexes so far proposed will generate broken XML. Because XML is more complex than you assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML tags, please use HTML parser.

For [a][/a], you can do like following

```
Match m=Regex.Match(@"[a b=""c"" d=""e""]Some multi line text[/a]", 
                    @"\[a b=""([^""]+)"" d=""([^""]+)""\](.*?)\[/a\]",
                    RegexOptions.Multiline);

m.Groups[1].Value
"c"
m.Groups[2].Value
"e"
m.Groups[3].Value
"Some multi line text"
```

Here is Regex.Replace (I am not that prefer though)

```
string inputStr = @"[a b=""[[[[c]]]]"" d=""e[]""]Some multi line text[/a]";
string resultStr=Regex.Replace(inputStr,
                            @"\[a( b=""[^""]+"")( d=""[^""]+"")?\](.*?)\[/a\]",
                            @"<a$1$2>$3</a>", 
                            RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: First of all I am not parsing HTML, its text with some tags that need to be converted to XML. Second, is there a direct way like using Regex.Replace function

Comment: You missed the question: the part d="e" is optional. I guess your Regex.Replace won't work.

Comment: If $2 doesn't contain anything, and then shouldn't be d="$2" in the output.

Comment: Though the answer is not what I am looking for, as it matched everything instead of just the attribute values. I figured it out, the best is to use the Match and a MatchEvaluator Delegate in the Regex.Replace method. Accepting your answer, as it was the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually thinking of processing (pseudo)-HTML using regexes,

**don't**

SO is filled with posts where regexes are proposed for HTML/XML and answers pointing out why this is a bad idea.

Suppose your multiline text ("which can be anything") contains

```
[a b="foo" [a b="bar"]]
```

a regex cannot detect this.

See the classic answer in:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

which has:

> I think it's time for me to quit the
>   post of Assistant Don't Parse HTML
>   With Regex Officer. No matter how many
>   times we say it, they won't stop
>   coming every day... every hour even.
>   It is a lost cause, which someone else
>   can fight for a bit. So go on, parse
>   HTML with regex, if you must. It's
>   only broken code, not life and death.
>   – bobince

Seriously. Find an XML or HTML DOM and populate it with your data. Then serialize it. That will take care of all the problems you don't even know you have got.

Comment: the first case: Its not that simple [ can be in between the text also, so you do that.

Comment: the second case: I am not parsing XML, I am converting some tags in text to XML like syntax.

Comment: But you can have "anything" in the content. That can include punctuation characters including HTML markup , snippets of HTML, etc. You will run into the same problems as parsing XHTML or XML with regex.

Comment: I have deleted my trivial solution as the OP now makes it clear that the regex has to deal with arbitrarily complex content.

Comment: The other part has already been taken care of. You are again confusing, I am not parsing HTML, and there can't be HTML markup or scripts per se. Its a text that I need to convert it to XML like for e.g. convert text to SSML, and that is the reason why we don't have <a b="c" d="e"> in the first place, instead we have our own text notation to mark text part [a b="c" d="e"]

Answer (score 0):

Would `some multiline text` include `[` and `]`? If not, you can just replace `[` with `<` and `]` with `>` using string.replace - no need of regex.

Update:
If it can be anything but `[/a]`, you can replace

```
^\[a([^\]]+)](.*?)\[/a]$
```

with

```
<a$1>$2</a>
```

I haven't escaped `]` and `/` in the regex - escape them if necessary to get

```
^\[a([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/a\]$
```

Comment: multi line text can be anything.