# How to replace square brackets with curly brackets using R's regex?

Tags: regex, r, pcre, brackets

Due to conversions between pandoc-citeproc and latex I'd like to replace this

`[@Fotheringham1981]`

with this

`\cite{Fotheringham1981}`
.

The issue with treating each bracket separately is illustrated in the reproducible example below.

```
x <- c("[@Fotheringham1981]", "df[1,2]")
x1 <- gsub("\\[@", "\\\\cite{", x)
x2 <- gsub("\\]", "\\}", x1)

x2[1] # good
## [1] "\\cite{Fotheringham1981}"

x2[2] # bad
## [1] "df[1,2}"
```

Seen a similar issue [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811969/regular-expression-to-replace-square-brackets-with-angle-brackets) for C#, but not using R's perly regex - any ideas?

### Edit:

It should be able to handle long documents, e.g.

```
old_rmd <- "$p = \alpha e^{\beta d}$ [@Wilson1971] and $p = \alpha d^{\beta}$
[@Fotheringham1981]."
new_rmd1 <- gsub("\\[@([^\\]]*)\\]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", old_rmd, perl = T) 
new_rmd2 <- gsub("\\[@([^]]*)]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", old_rmd) 

new_rmd1
## "$p = \alpha e^{\beta d}$ \\cite{Wilson1971} and $p = \alpha d^{\beta}$\n    \\cite{Fotheringham1981}."

new_rmd2
## [1] "$p = \alpha e^{\beta d}$ \\cite{Wilson1971} and $p = \alpha d^{\beta}$\n\\cite{Fotheringham1981}."
```

Comment: Bonus points for a regex that can do the opposite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
gsub("\\[@([^]]*)]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", x)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/CbnqsX)

Regex breakdown:

- `\\[@` - a literal `[@` symbol sequence
- `([^]]*)` - a capture group 1 that matches 0 or more occurrences of any symbol but a `]` (note that if `]` appears at the beginning of a character class, it does not need escaping)
- `]` -  a literal `]` symbol

You do not need to use `perl=T` with this one because the `]` inside a character class is not escaped. Otherwise, it would require using that option.

Also, I believe we should only escape what must be escaped. If there is a way to avoid [backslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/), we should. Thus, you can even use

```
gsub("[[]@([^]]*)]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", x)
```

Here is [another demo](http://ideone.com/4Jdti3)

**Why TRE-based regex works better than the PCRE one:**

In R 2.10.0 and later, the default regex engine is a modified version of Ville Laurikari's TRE engine [[source]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html). The [library's author states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRE_(computing)) that time spent for matching grows linearly with increasing of input text length, while memory requirements are almost constant (tens of kilobytes). TRE is also [said](http://laurikari.net/tre/about/) to use predictable and modest memory consumption and a quadratic worst-case time in the length of the used regular expression matching algorithm. That is why it seems best to rely on TRE rather than on PCRE regex when dealing with larger documents.

Comment: So you mean `[[]` is better than `\\[`  ?

Comment: :) No, it is the same. In a POSIX expression, escaping is not possible inside a character class, but is possible outside. I just showed a synonymic expression where no escaping takes place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capturing group.

```
x <- c("[@Fotheringham1981]", "df[1,2]")
gsub("\\[@([^\\]]*)\\]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", x, perl=T)
# [1] "\\cite{Fotheringham1981}" "df[1,2]"
```

or

```
gsub("\\[@(.*?)\\]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", x)
# [1] "\\cite{Fotheringham1981}" "df[1,2]"
```

Comment: ya, some people may got confused with yours.

Comment: I just want to stress that we should only escape what must be escaped. If there is a way to avoid [backslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/), we should.

Comment: @stribizhev your answer is more concise and works to convert my long .Rmd file - you should get the 'correct' answer IMO! Thanks also for your reply Av but it seems not to work for long documents.

Comment: @RobinLovelace What do you mean? He just avoid escaping. I don't know how the regex from him works on  string where mine would fail. You may consider this `gsub("\\[@([^][]*)]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", x)` also.

Comment: @RobinLovelace ya it fails you need to add `perl=T`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OK apologies

Answer (score 1):

This matches `[@` and then sets up a capture group, i.e. everything within (...), and then `.*?` matches the shortest string until `]` :

```
gsub("\\[(@.*?)\\]", "\\\\cite{\\1}", x)
## [1] "\\cite{@Fotheringham1981}" "df[1,2]"
```

Here is a railroad diagram of the regular expression:

```
\[(@.*?)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/es8IlDcirgylAK7i)