# Replacing square brackets with curly brackets in R

Tags: r, gsub

Can anybody tell me how to replace square brackets with curly brackets in R. For example `[1,2,3]` to `{1,2,3}`. I know it could be done with "gsub" function but do not know how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608060/how-to-replace-square-brackets-with-curly-brackets-using-rs-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a possible option using `gsub` twice:

```
gsub("\\]", "}", gsub("\\[", "{", "[1, 2, 3]"))
```

It first replaces `]` for `}` and then `[` for `{` to the resulting string.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `gsub` to remove the `[]` and then `paste` the `{}`

```
paste0("{", gsub("[][]", "", str1), "}")
#[1] "{1,2,3}"
```

---

Or another option is `chartr`

```
chartr("[]", "{}", str1)
#[1] "{1,2,3}"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "[1,2,3]"
```

Comment: the second solution is so easy to understand. Thanks a lot!!